# tag="value" and <tag>value</tag>

Tags: sql, xml, database, import

I have database in XML, which I need export to SQL Server DB.
So, I can export xml such as: tag="value"
But my XML is: `<tag>value</tag>`.

My query:

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (
userId INT,
userName NVARCHAR(50),
password NVARCHAR(50)
)
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml="my_XML"

INSERT INTO @tempTable<br />
SELECT Tbl.Col.value('@userId', 'INT'),<br />
       Tbl.Col.value('@userName', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),<br />
       Tbl.Col.value('@password', 'NVARCHAR(50)')<br />
FROM   @xml.nodes('//row') Tbl(Col)

SELECT * FROM @tempTable
```

Can I convert first case to second case?
Or maybe there are another way?

Sample of XML data:

```
<row>
<userId>1</userId>
<userName>Alpha</userName>
<password>1234</password>
</row>
<row>
<userId>2</userId>
<userName>Beta</userName>
<password>5678</password>
</row>
```

When I try to import it, I receive datatable with 2 rows with NULL cells.

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample of your xml data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want...?

```
 SELECT Tbl.Col.value('userId[1]','int'),
 Tbl.Col.value('userName[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
 Tbl.Col.value('password[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
 FROM @xml.nodes('//row') Tbl(Col)
```